# Mixing ink with alcohol, MEG and water

Tags: color, mixtures, dye

First of all, I'm not a chemist and my knowledge in chemistry is not that extensive. However, I would like ask the following question: are there any chemical reasons that would explain that mixing a blue ink with alcohol and MEG, lets say 3% as part of a volume of 1 L, gives a ways stronger blue than mixing in a big tank 3% of the same ink on a volume of 30000 L? Being in that last mix a greenish colour the result.

Comment: How do you measure the intensity of the blue color, exactly? Given the only variable that is different is the volume of solution, this is unlikely a chemical question and may have to do with the perception. There is a small chance that higher volume suggests greater surface area and quicker oxidation by oxygen from the air, but that's to be answered by an organic chemist once you provide additional info what the chemical composition of the blue ink was.

Comment: the intensity of the colour is measured by the sight of eye, the difference is clearly spotted. We know that sun light may dim the colour of the mixture but we rule that one out because the mixture happen in a closed tank, oxidation inside of the tank? I'll propose that as a possible explanation, the mixture though remains in the tank for only about 40 món.again I rinsed very well the mixing tank, check for leaks in pipes, also the flash point between tank and manual mixture and nothing..so I thought that there is some chemical reaction going on that escape to my knowledge.

Comment: If I find out what's going on I'll post it here. Thanks for your answer thought, for taking some time to try to help us. Highly appreciated